# MySQL Get values without Foreign Key Constraints AND Compare Dates Different Tables

Tags: mysql

Say I own a costume shop or something a long those lines.

tableA holds the information for the costume.

- barcode (fk REFERENCES tableB)
- type (i.e. Hulk, Superman etc.)
- hirageFee

tableB holds information relating to the hirage.

- barcode (REFERENCES tableA)
- hiredOn (date)
- dueBack (date)
- transaction no.

I am trying to write a query that will check if the costume is available to rent.

I can use the following to find all costumes that haven't been rented ever:

SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE barcode NOT IN (SELECT barcode FROM tableB)

and to check current rentals that are back in the store already:

SELECT * FROM tableB WHERE dueBack < ('enter-current-date');

But I am stuck on how to combine these queries or if that's the right approach to see/find all costumes currently in store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see what items in TableA that are not rented out you can restate the question as *which items doesn't have a rented out period that the current date falls in*

Expressed in SQL it would be a a query using a negated `exists` predicate with a correlated subquery, like this:

```
select * from TableA a
where not exists (
    select *
    from TableB b 
    where b.barcode = a.barcode
      and now() between hiredOn and dueBack
)
```

There are many other ways to achieve the same result, but I think this fits the semantics of the question well.

Comment: Awesome that works perfectly thanks! I might read up on some more advances query features such as exists, it seems handy.

Answer (score 0):

Or just use a join

```
select a.* from TableA a
left join TableB b
    on b.barcode = a.barcode
      and now() between hiredOn and dueBack
where b.barcode is null;
```